# Marklogic lexicons: understanding cts:element-values

Tags: search, marklogic, lexicon

I am trying to understand the usage of

```
cts:element-values($element-names as xs:QName*,[$start as xs:anyAtomicType?])
```

I was under the impression that the above function returns values from the specified element value lexicon, starting with $start.
On Querying:

```
cts:element-values(xs:QName("ts:title"), "He")
```

I was expecting results starting with "He" only, but I have also got results such as:

(as I scroll down)
I Feel Fine

I Get Around

I would like to know what exactly does $start specify ?

Comment: can you confirm that you have values staring with 'H' and 'He'?

Comment: Hi Tamas,
I have got values starting with "He" and "H" in my results. I am confused why am I getting additional values such as "I Feel Fine" in my results.

Comment: I believe that this function returns the values starting from your start position and then continues on until it the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of `$start` not as a starting prefix but as a starting location in the list. You're getting all the values from that point onward.

To limit by prefix you want to use `cts:element-value-match` which accepts a `$pattern`. http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-match

Comment: just out of curiosity how can I pattern match double type range indices? cts:element-value-match(xs:QName("rating"), 7); (: where rating has values like 7.1, 7.2 etc :)

Comment: Assuming a single value per fragment, you could add a `cts:element-range-query` as the query constraint. You're right though, the API for `cts:element-value-match` allows any atomic type but I've never tried it with floats.

Answer (score 1):

`cts:element-values` and the like return values greater or equal to `$start` value. It really is just a start place for all values, until limit is depleted.

If you are looking for a function that returns values matching a particular pattern, you probably want to use [`cts:element-value-match`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-match) instead:

```
cts:element-value-match(xs:QName("title"), "He*")
```

HTH!